# string comparing query with chinese chars - Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle, special-characters, utf

I'm having trouble executing a simple query such as the following

```
select * from table_name where variabe_name like '在职'
```

the problem is the chinese chars. Those chars are in the table (I just copied them after doing a select * from table, so the displaying of the chinese chars works just fine) but it doesn't seem to work. When it execute the query, it returns 0 rows.

I' ve also tried

```
select * from table_name where variabe_name like '%在职%'
```

and

```
select * from table_name where variabe_name = '在职'
```

But that doesn't work either.

Any clue of what the problem might be?

Thnaks a lot

Comment: look at this [thread](http://forums.devshed.com/oracle-development-96/oracle-10g-chinese-charecter-issue-708247.html)

Comment: I'd suggest to try LIKEC instead of LIKE to handle composite characters. (Or possibly LIKE2 or LIKE4)

Comment: May be `where variabe_name like unistr( '%\4E2D\6587%' )` or `where variabe_name = unistr( '\4E2D\6587' )`. Here is the link [link](http://www.sqlsnippets.com/en/topic-13406.html)

Comment: @Chandra - if he can see the Chinese characters when doing a select * from table then the database is storing the data and his client appears to also have the right NLS settings, otherwise it wouldnt display the Chinese from the select so that is different to the thread you linked to which doesnt show the data when selected

Comment: @DanielX2010 - Can you post a describe of the table, and the result of the select just to ensure everything matches up and maybe a list of the nls parameters as well.

Comment: What is your client? I had the same problem, I could see native texts when selecting, but because of nls_lang problems in my Windows Registry the native texts didn't passed correctly from my Client (which was PLSQL Developer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

==> Found solution: put 'N' before the chinese characters, so that they are interpreted as Unicode. Like: where field like N'罐'

Answer (score 1):

```
 SQL> create table mytbl (data_col varchar2(200));
 Table created
 SQL> insert into mytbl values('在职'); 
 1 row inserted.
 SQL> commit;
 Commit complete.
 SQL> select * from mytbl where data_col like '%在职%';
 DATA_COL                                                                                                                                                                                               
 -----------
 在职 

 SQL> SELECT * FROM nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET';
 PARAMETER                      VALUE                                  
 ------------------------------ ----------------------------------------
 NLS_CHARACTERSET               AL32UTF8
```

Your `NLS_CHARACTERSET` should be set to `AL32UTF8`. So try

```
 SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_CHARACTERSET = 'AL32UTF8';
```

Also make sure that parameter `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` is set to `UTF8`.

```
 SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET = 'UTF8';
```